# APC making PHP 5.3 slower?

Tags: php, apache, apc

I recently learned about APC (I know, I'm late to the show) and decided to try it out on my development server. I did some benchmarking with ApacheBench, and to my surprise I've found that things are running *slower* than before.

I haven't made any code optimizations to use `apc_fetch` or anything, but I was under the impression the opcode caching should make a positive impact on its own?

```
C:\Apache24\bin>ab -n 1000 http://localhost/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1178079 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.2
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        22820 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   120.910 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        95
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 95, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      23181893 bytes
HTML transferred:       22819893 bytes
Requests per second:    8.27 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       120.910 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       120.910 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          187.23 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.4      0       1
Processing:   110  120   7.2    121     156
Waiting:       61   71   7.1     72     103
Total:        110  121   7.2    121     156

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    121
  66%    122
  75%    123
  80%    130
  90%    131
  95%    132
  98%    132
  99%    137
 100%    156 (longest request)
```

Here's the APC section of my php.ini. I've left most things at the default except for expanding the default size to 128MB instead of 32.

```
[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.enable_cli = 1
apc.ttl=3600
apc.user_ttl=3600
apc.shm_size = 128M
apc.slam_defense = 0
```

Am I doing something wrong, or do I just need to use apc_fetch/store to really get a benefit from APC?

Thanks for any insight you guys can give.

Comment: _"Note:  On Windows, APC needs a temp path to exist, and be writable by the web server. It checks the TMP, TEMP and USERPROFILE environment variables in that order"_  Does this path exist?

Comment: APC should make a difference... do you have both before and after AB figures, or just after?

Comment: And be aware that a lot of other factors, such as bad database queries or file access can have a big adverse overhead

Comment: TMP and TEMP both exist; I don't have the before numbers anymore but I'll try disabling and re-running. Even if there are other things going on, APC shouldn't make that WORSE, right?

Comment: is the apc.enabled=0 or am I seeing something wrong??

Comment: My fault, I was experimenting w/ turning it off and I pasted the version w/ it off. Fixed in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling APC with default settings will make a noticeable (to say the least) difference in response times for your PHP script. You don't have to use any of its specific store/fetch functions to get benefits from APC. In fact, normally you don't even need a benchmark to tell the difference; the difference should be apparent by simply navigating through your site.

If you don't see any difference and your benchmarks don't have some kind of error, then I'd suggest that you start debugging the issue (enable error reporting, check the logs, etc).